# How to force LyX to convert a GraphViz file into a vector format

Tags: lyx, diagrams, dot2tex

In the "Converters" section in LyX preferences, I have the two following converters automatically defined for GraphViz:

- Graphviz Dot -> PNG
- Graphviz Dot -> EPS

When I export my document as PDF, the DOT diagrams are converted to PNG and the resulting file size is quite big. I've tried to remove the PNG converter, or change it to SVG, but it doesn't work.

How can I force LyX to convert the dot diagrams to a vector format by default?

Comment: Is it possible to convert directly to PDF? If so, try that. (TeX can't use SVG files, so that won't help.)

Comment: Strange, in the Graphviz Dot, the "Vector graphics format" is checked and according to Help > Customization, "If an included graphic is not already in pdf, png, or jpg format, it is converted to pdf if the vector format option is set, and otherwise to png." There might be more nuggets of useful information in that manual. If after reading the relevant parts, you think it's a bug, please send an email to lyx-devel@lists.lyx.org with a minimal complete example (including of course a Graphviz Dot file), your LyX version and operating system, and the output from starting LyX with lyx -dbg graphics

Comment: You should have a look to package dot2texi, which requires dot2tex facility for conversion. The quality of exported graph will increase significantly.

Comment: I just tried this with LyX 2.1.3 under Windows 8.1, GraphViz 2.28, with a simple DOT graph saved to `sample.dot` that I inserted with Insert > Graphics... The generated PDF (using Document > View [PDF (XeTeX)] was 2k in size, and when I zoomed in as far as I could in Acrobat Reader, the graph contents were vectorial.